# Reduce space between header and icons

Tags: html, css, layout, position, icons

I'm working on a project and had the following code snippet:

```
<h2 style="color: #818181;">Details</h2>
<p><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> xxxxxxx@gmail.com<br>
<i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 12345678<br>
<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> 1 Yeet Street, Azerbaijan</p>
```

This left me this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQayg.png)

Is there any way that I can reduce the line break between the header and the icons without the icons starting on a new line to their text?

Answer (score 1):

The vertical space is a combination of the default top/bottom `margins` of both the `h2` and the `p` elements.  You will need to add styles to reduce/remove the `margin`, `margin-top` and/or `margin-bottom` using a CSS stylesheet:

```
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

p {
 margin: 0;
}
```

Or using the inline styles:

```
<h2 style="color: #818181; margin: 0">Details</h2>
<p style="margin-top: 0;"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> xxxxxxx@gmail.com<br>
<i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 12345678<br>
<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> 1 Yeet Street, Azerbaijan</p>
```